# Displaying input value without a submit button to another page using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyup

I am trying to display the result of an input value to another page. But this input does not have a submit button.

Thus, I am using `keyup` to store the input data.

I have 2 pages, `index1.php` and `index2.php`

**index1.php:**

```
<form>
    <input type="text" name="nameValidation" id="nameValidation" placeholder="Name">
    </form>

    <div id="display"></div>
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $('#nameValidation').keyup(function() {
                var nameValisession = $('#display').text($(this).val());
                sessionStorage.setItem("nameValiSession", nameValisession);
            }); 
        }); 
    </script>
```

So, what I am doing here is that I am using the `keyup` function to get the latest result and storing it as a variable. And then, I am assigning that variable into a `sessionStorage`.

**index2.php:**

```
    <div id="display"></div>
    <script>
    var nameValisession = sessionStorage.getItem("nameValiSession");
    document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = nameValisession;
    </script>
```

Here, I am just trying to retrieve the value of the variable `nameValisession`

However, this is not working for me. How do I go about sending the input value from `index1.php` to `index2.php`?

In the [tutorial website (example 1)](https://lage.us/Javascript-Pass-Variables-to-Another-Page.html) , it works perfectly for me when I tried their code.

```
Javascript in Page 1:
var favoritemovie = "Shrek";
sessionStorage.setItem("favoriteMovie", favoritemovie);

Javascript in Page 2:
var favoritemovie = sessionStorage.getItem("favoriteMovie");
console.log(favoritemovie);
```

So, can someone point me in the right direction on how to go about fixing the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is because `nameValisession` will hold a jQuery object, as that's what's returned from `text()`, not the actual text value itself, and you cannot place objects in to localStorage. To fix this separate the variable declaration and text update steps.

I'd also suggest using the `input` event instead of `keyup`, as it also captures content added via the mouse:

```
$(function() {
  $('#nameValidation').on('input', function() {
    var nameValisession = $(this).val();
    $('#display').text(nameValisession);
    sessionStorage.setItem("nameValiSession", nameValisession);
  }); 
});
```

Comment: I tried this, but it still doesn't fetch the result to `index2.php`

Comment: Whoops, thanks :) Have you checked in dev tools to ensure the value has been set in localstorage?

Comment: It doesn't record in the console, you need to check local data in dev tools. This is what it looks like in Chrome: https://i.imgur.com/HKsRHpT.png

Comment: Rory, yes I noticed that in `index1.php`, I have that value. But in `index2.php` , it is not there.

Comment: I tried again, yes it does save the value in `index1.php`, but not at `index2.php`

Comment: Have you disabled session storage then, as that's not how it works. Are `index1.php` and `index2.php` on the same domain?

Comment: I am using localhost (xampp). They are in the same folder.

Comment: I can't really be of any more assistance then I'm afraid as it should be working. If the value is set in sessionStorage it will be available to all pages on that same domain until the session ends. I cannot think of a reason, beyond a mistake somewhere, that this would not work.

Comment: Later, in a few hours, I'll try this on a domain instead. Maybe its got to do with the localhost. If its all good, I'll vote your answer as correct. Thanks for your help Rory!

Comment: Rory, I was testing it all wrong. Yes, your code works!